# Magento 2: Does Module Sequence Impact Layout Handle XML Loading Order?

Tags: magento2, layout, configuration

Do the `<sequence/>` tags in `module.xml` files impact the order Magento will process layout handle XML files in?  My preliminary research says *no*, but that seems wrong so I'm looking for confirmation/proof that they don't (proof == source code points where layout handle XML file paths are generated and loaded)

If the sequence tags don't impact layout handle XML file loading order -- is there a way to change the module order these files are loaded in?

Specific problem I'm trying to solve is if I have the following loaded before the container is actually aded to the page

```
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">    
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">product.info.media.image</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Magento barfs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sequence in `module.xml` has an impact on `app/etc/config.php`. This file gets updated when you run `bin/magento module:enable Vendor_ModuleName` so if you have added/changed sequences I'd suggest disabling your module and then re-enabling it.  Updating your `module.xml` file and clearing your cache isn't enough here, you'll need to do a full `disable` re-`enable` cycle to get Magento to see sequence changes during development.

The sort order of modules in the `config.php` file is then used for all other configuration file loading as per Anton's comment [here.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/953#issuecomment-73667752)

The code locations in that comment are a bit out of date. This is the code for the sequence sorting https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php#L131

Update 2:

app/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="fileSource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Layout\File\Collector\Aggregated\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="pageLayoutFileSource" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileCollectorAggregated</argument>
        <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

which references a page layout file collector in the same di.xml

```
<virtualType name="pageLayoutFileCollectorAggregated" type="Magento\Framework\View\Layout\File\Collector\Aggregated">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseFiles" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileSourceBaseSorted</argument>
        <argument name="themeFiles" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileSourceThemeSorted</argument>
        <argument name="overrideBaseFiles" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileSourceOverrideBaseSorted</argument>
        <argument name="overrideThemeFiles" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileSourceOverrideThemeSorted</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

the one that looks of interest to us is `pageLayoutFileSourceBaseSorted` still in the same di.xml

```
<virtualType name="pageLayoutFileSourceBaseSorted" type="Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Decorator\ModuleDependency">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="subject" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutFileSourceBaseFiltered</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

`Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Decorator\ModuleDependency` does the following sorting

```
protected function getModulePriority($moduleName)
{
    if ($this->orderedModules === null) {
        $this->orderedModules = $this->moduleList->getNames();
    }
    $result = array_search($moduleName, $this->orderedModules);
    // Assume unknown modules have the same priority, distinctive from known modules
    if ($result === false) {
        return -1;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

where `moduleList` is based on `Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList` which in turn uses the Loader mentioned way above.

Comment: +1 for good information, but that seems to leave an open question -- are layout handle XML files considered configuration files, or are they *something else*.

Comment: Commenting for google posterity -- the configuration loading **does** obey the sequence settings, but the sequence isn't set on a cache clear, its set on a module enable/disable.

Comment: Life saver! I took me quite a while before I noticed that this was happening.

Comment: And what about the layout-xml in the theme (app/design/AwesomeTheme/default/..? Are all these layout-xml's merged *after* de modules in the vendor and app/code locations, in the same order as explained hereabove?