# If $resultPage->addHandle() is used in a controller for a vendor module, can't get my module to modify that layout xml

Tags: layout

I need to modify the layout xml for another module from my Magento 2 module. In this module they use in the controller execute() method a way to add their layout xml:

```
$resultPage->addHandle('custom_module_layout');
```

I need to use the custom_module_layout.xml in my module to modify a template and block class, but it seems Magento 2 doesn't look in my module for this layout file even when I have it in the proper location and my module.xml file has  set to load their module first.

Is this a Magento 2 bug or just way it does things? So I would have to add a plugin to execute() to add my own layout xml file, or is there a better way?

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Sorry was just a dumb thing on my part, I had disabled and re-enabled the module but was checking a different layout file for a ui component. Now it's working on the original layout xml file I was trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, was just an issue that I needed to disable and enable my module for the layout load order changes to take effect. Looking at app/etc/config.php it seemed the load order was ok but it actually wasn't.

Reference: [Magento 2: Does Module Sequence Impact Layout Handle XML Loading Order?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102441/magento-2-does-module-sequence-impact-layout-handle-xml-loading-order)

So I just did:

```
bin/magento module:disable my_module
```

Then:

```
bin/magento module:enable my_module
```